# How do I unlock portrait mode in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, settings

My screen has a lock with an almost full bordering circle around it ending with an arrow. This is located in the top right of my screen. Just inside the battery %. How do I turn this lock off so I can use landscape mode?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is the [lock rotation icon](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3805). You will notice that when you turn your iPhone (say, in Safari) it will stay in portrait.

To disable it:

On iOS 7+ :

- Open the Control Centre by sliding your finger from the bottom of the screen to the top
- Tap the button a the top right (here circled in red)
  [image]

---

iOS 6

- Double tap on home button
- Then slide the multitask bar to the left (where the Sound controls are)
- And on the left you'll find the button to unlock this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 7+:

- Slide your finger from the bottom of the screen upwards. A menu called Control Center should appear.

[image: Control Center]

- Click on the lock icon.